# Implementing ssl on z/os

Tags: ssl, mainframe, zos

Does anybody knows how to implement SSL on the z/OS telnet server?

I've tried looking in the IBM sites and found how to implement ssl with MQ or other software's but didn't found information how to implant on z/OS itself.

Comment: Not sure your question makes sense - SSL applies to a specific connection; you can’t apply SSL to an OS.

Comment: Implementing SSL is a fairly broad question.  As @SteveIves pointed out.  You mention MQ so it sound like your question could be narrowed to a more specific one like, I'm having difficulty getting (choose your product or area) to run with transport level security.  Or, perhaps its more of a challenge with the security manager and Ring management.  Can you provide more details on the problem and what you've tried ?

Comment: Re-reading the question a few times ... are you trying to implement direct SSH access ?

Comment: I mean to implement the ssl on the telnet protocol while logging in to the os. I haven't found any information about implementing it so I have no Idea where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any telnet-connection on your z/OS-server you should have something like the following in your telnet configuration dataset:

```
BEGINVTAM                               
  PORT 1234                             
  DEFAULTLUS AB.0001..AB.9999 ENDDEFAULTLUS                         
  DEFAULTAPPL TSO                     
ENDVTAM                                 
TELNETPARMS                             
  PORT 1234                       
ENDTELNETPARMS
```

Simply changing `PORT` to `SECUREPORT` should be enough to enable SSL/TLS on this connection. To configure additional TLS-parameters for the connection you can add more parameters to the `TELNETPARMS`-section or define them in a `TELNETGLOBALS`-section for all ports.

Using `TTLSPORT` instead will allow the use of application transparent TLS (AT-TLS) on the port which requires additional configuration in an AT-TLS policy agent (if your installation already has one running).

For further information you should look at the "IP Configuration Reference" and "IP Configuration Guide" for the z/OS Communication Server which both have a chapter about configuring the telnet-server.

Comment: Question on this answer: is this form of Telnet supported by any out-of-the-box Telnet client, or is it only between the Telnet endpoint and an AT-TLS agent somewhere else in the network? If the latter, wouldn't this leave the traffic from the actual Telnet client to the AT-TLS agent unencrypted? Seems to me that SSH would be a way better solution than this?

Comment: Hi, AT-TLS is just a means to provide a TLS-Port on the z/OS-side, so any Telnet-client that is able to speak TLS can open a encrypted connection. SSH might be ppreferable in some cases, the main usecase for the Telnet-Server is providing TN3270-sessions for green-screen applications running in a 3270-emulation.

Comment: I learned something today...thanks. Forgetting TN3270, I never thought about a Telenet client with TLS built in - the simple one I use everyday on MacOS and Linux doesn't do this...I always assumed that's why SSH (or a VPN) was the alternative. But then I did some searching and found that there are indeed some Telnet clients with TLS/SSL built in, as you say. I do quite a bit of remote access that's of the non-3270 variety (UNIX Services shell sessions), so this might be something to try in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding an "out-of-the-box" Telnet client, be sure you don't confuse "telnet" and "tn3270".  An "out-of-the-box" telnet client like PuTTY usually doesn't support the 3270-specific data streams--standard telnet would be handled in z/OS by OMVS.  TN3270 support is handled by a program named EZBTNINI, which usually runs via a PROC named TN3270.

TN3270 session traffic can be encrypted, but the TN3270 emulators (like BlueZone or PCOMM) must be told to use implicit or explicit TLS when they communicate with VTAM via a TTLSPORT port.

To use TLS with 3270 terminals on z/OS, you must run the Policy Agent. Suppose you have these statements in your TN3270 PROFILE for port 1234:

```
; Add secure port 1234 for TLS
 TELNETPARMS
 TTLSPORT 1234             ; TTLSPORT for Policy Agent & AT-TLS
   CONNTYPE SECURE         ; Require TLS
   NOSEQUENTIALLU
ENDTELNETPARMS

BEGINVTAM
  PORT 1234
  DEFAULTLUS
    TCP00001..TCP00030
  ENDDEFAULTLUS
  ...other BEGINVTAM block statements
ENDVTAM
```

Here a sample pagent_TTLS.conf that could be used to specify the TLS options for port 1234:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#--- AT-TLS policy for TN3270 --------------------------------------------
TTLSRule                           TN3270-Server-1234
{
   LocalAddr                       ALL
   LocalPortRange                  1234
   Direction                       Both
   Priority                        253
   TTLSGroupActionRef              gAct-TN3270
   TTLSEnvironmentActionRef        eAct-TN3270
   TTLSConnectionActionRef         cAct-TN3270
}
TTLSGroupAction                    gAct-TN3270
{
   TTLSEnabled                     On
   GroupUserInstance               1
}
TTLSEnvironmentAction              eAct-TN3270
{
   HandshakeRole                   Server
   EnvironmentUserInstance         0
   TTLSKeyringParmsRef             kyRingParms
}

TTLSConnectionAction               cAct-TN3270
{
   HandshakeRole                   ServerWithClientAuth
   TTLSCipherParmsRef              cipher1234-BlueZone_Ciphers
   TTLSConnectionAdvancedParmsRef  cAdv-TN3270-1234
   CtraceClearText                 On
   Trace                           1
}
TTLSConnectionAdvancedParms        cAdv-TN3270-1234
{
   ApplicationControlled           On
   SecondaryMap                    Off
   SSLv3                           On
   TLSv1                           On
   TLSv1.1                         On
   TLSv1.2                         On
}
TTLSKeyringParms                   kyRingParms
{
   Keyring                         MackDev
}
TTLSCipherParms                    cipher1234-BlueZone_Ciphers
{
# Bluezone 3DES Ciphers
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

# Bluezone AES 128
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

# Bluezone "Strong Only"
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

# Bluezone RC4
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

# Bluezone AES 256
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
   V3CipherSuites                  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

}
#--- AT-TLS policy for TN3270 End ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: "...you must run the Policy Agent..." - no, only if you want to use AT-TLS via `TTLSPORT`. `SECUREPORT` will enable TLS just as well without the need for the Policy Agent.